# Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime?' and 'int'

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

My code is like this but I need to validate if `RemainingDay` is more than 10  then it will not show you messagebox for remaining days

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(dr[0]) == DateTime.Today)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your trail period is expired. Please purchase this Software.", "SMS");
    Application.Exit();
}
else
{
    newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[0]);
    RemainingDay = newDate.Subtract(TodayDate);

    MessageBox.Show("You have " + RemainingDay.Days + " days Left.", "SMS");
    this.Hide();

    frmMainMenu frm = new frmMainMenu();
    frm.Show();
    frm.lblUser.Text = txtUserName.Text;
}
```

I tried the code below:

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(dr[0]) == DateTime.Today)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your trail period is expired. Please purchase this Software.", "SMS");
    Application.Exit();
}
else
{
    newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[0]);
    RemainingDay = newDate.Subtract(TodayDate);

    if (RemainingDay <= 10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have " + RemainingDay.Days + " days Left.", "SMS");
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Hide();
        frmMainMenu frm = new frmMainMenu();
        frm.Show();
        frm.lblUser.Text = txtUserName.Text;
    }                        
}
```

The above code is giving me this error :

> Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime?' and 'int'

Please help me.

Comment: Read the error message (again) as it says exactly what is wrong. Now, *why* is there a DateTime? used in the comparison when an int is expected (or vice-versa)?

Comment: I think Microsoft should add some funny videos with [minions](http://despicableme.wikia.com/wiki/Minions) which explain meaning of error messages. Plain text is very hard to understand..

Comment: @user2864740: `RemainingDay` is date value. Not Day value

Comment: your error message doesn't agree with the code you have posted - your code doesn't use a `>=` anywhere.  You should show the actual code and actual error message if you want people to be able to help you to the best of their abilities

Comment: Why are people voting to close this as off topic?  Seems like perfectly reasonable question to me.  they have shown their attempts to solve the problem, and stated their issue quite clearly. Closing should not be done based on how simple you find the issue, everyone is a beginner at some point, you can't judge the questions on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `RemainingDay` variable is a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.timespan.aspx) which is the difference between the `DateTime` given and today's date. You can't see if a `TimeSpan` is less than a number - it doesn't make any sense.

What you want is to get the number of days difference between the dates, which the `TimeSpan` holds in the [`.Days`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which will give you (from MSDN)

> the days component of the time interval represented by the current `TimeSpan` structure.

so use that instead.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
if (RemainingDay <= 10)
```

To

```
if (RemainingDay.Days <= 10)
```